# Google Sign-In Implementation

Tags: python, reactjs, next.js, google-signin, fastapi

I've my product based on React/FastAPI tech stack. Simple `client <-> api` architecture.

The React app asks for username/password and then authenticates against the apis. If everything was fine, apis answer with a JWT token back.

Now, what I'd like to do is add social logins and so I started from Google. Unfortunately I didn't find the current best practices to integrate Google Sign-in in such architecture, all JS and nothing more. So after digging a bit on pages and pages of documentation, this is the approach I took:

- I created 2 api endpoints `/google/login` and `/google/callback`
- The first endpoint calls google to generate the SSO url
- The second endpoint is called back by Google so I can verify the request
- If you try this flow using the APIs directly, it works like a charm.

But I've to use it through my React website. So this is what I did:

- I've a button on the website (the classic Google Sign-In button) that when clicked, calls my /google/login api endpoint and gets the SSO url
- The React client app redirect the user to the SSO URL
- The user does the sign in with google
- As a call back url on Google, I've set a route on my React app so when called it just takes the payload and headers and forwards them to my /google/callback api endpoint, which verifies the request and if everything is fine answer with a valid JWT

This flow is somehow working, but I've some issues with Brave for example, where the redirect after the Google login doesn't happen (actually it happens only if you reload the page).

So I'm wondering, is this the right approach to implement Google Oauth2 flow?

Comment: good question, I'm curious as well.